# Sound Channel map incorrect on an ION 330 ASRock 

Tags: 12.04, sound, nvidia, pulseaudio

I have a ION 330 ASRock just updated on Precise and the sound channel mapping is incorrect.

Channel map is set as follow:

```
Front Left = Front left 
Center = Rear Left 
Front Right = Font Right 
Rear Right = LFE 
Rear Left = Center 
LFE = Rear Right
```

I am testing the sound channel using

```
speaker-test -c 2 -t wav
```

Can some one tell me how I can remap easily?

I have tried several possible changes to `/etc/pulse/defaut.pa` unsuccessfully.

Comment: I'm having the same problem since 10.10, haven't found any way to fix this :-( we are out of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have an ASRock ION 330 with 12.04 LTS.

I'm not engineer, so may this maybe incorrect, but channel map  works perfectly in my ASRock ION 330.

If you output sound on **HDMI**, open `extra-hdmi.conf` by running this in the terminal:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf
```

**edit**

```
[Mapping hdmi-surround]
...
channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
...
```

**to**

```
[Mapping hdmi-surround]
...
channel-map = front-left,front-right,front-center,lfe,rear-left,rear-right
...
```

and edit [Mapping hdmi-surround-extra1], [Mapping hdmi-surround-extra2], [Mapping hdmi-surround-extra] in the same way.

Save the file, then run

```
pulseaudio -k
```

to apply the changes.

In Sound configuration, choose "**Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)**".